# how to access variables in a class but outside a function?

Tags: php, class

i made the following code:

```
<?php
 class hoi {
  public $a = 1;
   function test()
   { 
    echo $this->$a; /* reference to alocal scope variable? */ 
   } 
  }
 $hoi = new hoi;
 $hoi->test();
?>
```

I try to echo $a but this does not work,
how can i echo variables declared inside the class but outside the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
$this->a
```

Using an additional `$` in there is a "variable variable" for properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
class hoi {
    public $a = 1;
    function test() { 
        echo $this->a;/* the variable is accessed like this - no need for the $ */
    } 
}
$hoi = new hoi();/* required as there is no __construct() method */
$hoi->test();
```

Comment: *"required as there is no __construct() method"* - huh?

Comment: a class that uses the __construct() function can be invoked without needing the `()` can it not? Perhaps I'm mistaken - but I thought that you needed to call the class with `()` if it had no defined `__construct` function/method

Comment: The existence or non-existence of a constructor makes absolutely no difference for the instantiation syntax. It works without parentheses either way.

Comment: so i discover - still, makes no difference it was the `$` that was the issue anyway

Comment: Maybe you should delete your wrong comment to get some upvotes.

Comment: aside from that erronous comment regarding the constructor the actual answer was right. At least from that I learned a little snippet which I had overlooked over the years